# How do I add a list of keys without values(or a single value) to an existing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to add a list of keys without values to an existing dictionary in python.

```py
new_keys_to_add = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
my_dict = {'a':100, 'b':51, 'c':215}
```

I guess I can do the following:

```py
my_dict.update(zip(new_keys_to_add, [0 for i in new_keys_to_add]))
```

Is there any way that I can do better without creating a new list?

Or

```py
for i in new_keys_to_add:
    my_dict[i]=0
```

But it seems there should be a way to avoid using loops for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, they should have values.

You can use `dict.fromkeys()`. It accepts an iterable of keys and a value that is used for all the keys in that iterable. It's default to `None` if you don't specify.

```py
new_keys_to_add = ["e", "f", "g", "h"]
my_dict = {"a": 100, "b": 51, "c": 215}
my_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(new_keys_to_add, 0))
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'a': 100, 'b': 51, 'c': 215, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0}
```

Comment: Or use None instead of 0 as the default value which is what will happen if it is left undefined in `.fromkeys`

Comment: But doesn't fromkeys() create a new dictionary? Is that better than creating a new list or using a loop?

Comment: @saba it does. Do you concern about speed or memory? it'll be done pretty fast.

Comment: @S.B This will be done in another loop which will create lots of small lists; so I'd like to avoid creating any more lists or dictionaries where I can.

Comment: @saba it creates a new dictionary and updates the old one with this new dictionary. that's it. Where are the small lists?

Comment: The small lists will come from the function, in which these codes will belong to. The function will go through a file, find patterns, and spew out lists. And the values from the lists will be the keys. I'm asking these questions not because I know this will bog down my codes, but rather because I don't really know how python works behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid intermediate list/dicts, you can always use a generator:

```
my_dict.update((k, 0) for k in new_keys_to_add)
```

Whether this part is really worth optimizing is another question (spoiler: it's not).